# How to enable basic security for Spring Cloud Data Flow Server on kubernetes?

Tags: security, minikube, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have deployed Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) version 2.4.0 on Kubernetes v1.17.4 using minikube v1.8.2 based on this reference. [Documentation | Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/)

I want to enable Basic Authentication on SCDF. [17.2 Basic Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-security.html)
However I can not find the relevant documentation for Kubernetes or Spring to change the SCDF pod security.

```
17.2 Basic Authentication
Basic Authentication can be enabled by adding the following to application.yml or via environment variables:

security:
  basic:
    enabled: true                                                     
    realm: Spring Cloud Data Flow
```

Should I change it using data flow config server shell? if so what is the command?

Or should I change security using kubectl update resource yaml? How do I put the security config in pod yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of SCDF which is not currently maintained. I suggest you update to a recent release version from [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow#learn).

The basic authentication got removed in the later versions of SCDF and the authentication/authorization is now supported via OAuth 2.

You can refer the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-security) for more information.

Comment: It's not that old. But my question is, how can I enable OAuth2 (for example) in SCDF that deployed on kubernetes? the configuration in mentioned help, illustrates local configuration and says nothing about configure security on kubernetes version.